# Replace missing values with mean

Tags: r, na

```
  [1] 10  2  4  1 10 10  1  1  1  1  1  3  3  9  1  1  1 10  1 10  7  1 NA  1  7  1  1  1  1  1  1  5  1  1  1  1  1 10  7 NA  3 10  1  1  1  9
 [47]  1  1  8  3  4  5  8  8  5  6  1 10  2  3  2  8  2  1  2  1 10  9  1  1  2  1 10  4  2  1  1  3  1  1  1  1  2  9  4  8 10  1  1  1  1  1
 [93]  1  1  1  1  1  6 10  5  5  1  3  1  3 10 10  1  9  2  9 10  8  3  5  2 10  3  2  1  2 10 10  7  1 10  1 10  1  1  1 10  1  1  2  1  1  1
[139] NA  1  1  5  5  1 NA  8  2  1 10  1 10  5  3  1 10  1  1 NA 10 10  1  1  3 NA  2 10  1  1  1  1  1  1 10 10 10  1  1  1 10  1  1  1 10 10
[185]  1  8 10  8  1  8 10  1  1  1  1  7  1  1  1 10 10  1  1  1 10  5  1  1  1 10  8  1 10 10  5  1  1  4  1  1 10  5  8 10  1 10  5  1 10  7
[231]  8  1 10  1 NA 10  2  9 10  2  1  1  5  1  2 10  9  1 NA  1 10 10 10  8 10  1  1  1  8 10 10 10 10  3  1 10 10  4  1 10  1 10  4  1 NA  1
[277]  1  1  7  1  1 10 10 10 10 10  1  5 10  1  1 NA 10 NA 10  5 NA  1 10  4  1 10  1 10 10  1  1  3  5  1  1  1  1  1 NA 10  8  1  5 10 NA  1
[323] 10  1  1 10  1  4 10  8  1  1 10 10  1 10  1  1 10 10  1  1  1 10  1  1  1  1  8  1  1  3 10  1  1  3 10  4  7 10 10  3  3  1  1 10 10  1
[369]  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1 10  1  1  1  1 10  1  1  2  1 10  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  9  1  1  4  1  1  1  1  2  1  1 NA  4  1 10
[415]  3 10  1  2  1  3 10  1  1  1 10  1  2  1  1  1  1  1  1  8 10  1  1  1  1 10  4  3  2  1  1  1  1  1 10  1  1  1 10  1  6 10  3  1  1  1
[461]  5  1  1  1  4 10 10  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1 10  1  1  5 10  1  3  1 10  3  4  1 10  1 10  5  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  5
[507]  4  1  1  1  1  1  1 10 10  1  1  1 10  1  1  5 10  1  1  1  1  1  1 10  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  2  1  1  1  1  1 10  1  1  5  1  1  1
[553]  5  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1 10  1  3 10  5 10 10  1  1  2  1  1  1  1  1  1 10 10  1  1  1 10  1  3  1  1 10 10  1 10  1  1  1  1
[599]  1  1  1  1  1 10  8  1  1 10  1 10  2 10  1  1  1  1 NA  1  1  1  2  1  1  1  4  6  5  1  1  1  1  1  3  1  1  1  2  1  1  1  1  1  1  1
[645]  1  1  1  2  1  4  1  1  1  1  1  1  1 10  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  5  8  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1 10 10  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1
[691]  5  1  1  2  1  3  4  5
```

those are the values in the seventh column, I want to replace NAs with column means. my entire data set is in the variable  df

Comment: Tip: `df` is already the name of a function in base R, so it's not ideal to use it as an object name.

Comment: There are no "columns" in that result. There is a `colMeans` function with an na.rm parameter.

Comment: @arvi1000, what's the potential damage you foresee?

Comment: It means you can't easily use the df function, should you want to, and also I think it makes the code less readable when keywords that normally mean one thing in most R contexts (like a function in base) now mean something else (like the name of a data.frame). Imagine a data.frame called `sum` or `lapply`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's two questions here:

1) How do I get the mean of a set of numbers excluding `NA`?

```
Mean = mean(df[, 7], na.rm = TRUE)
```

2) How do I replace `NA` with a specified value in a column?

```
df[,7][is.na(df[,7])] <- Mean
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
df[is.na(df[ , 7]) , 7] <- mean(df[ , 7], na.rm = TRUE)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
df[is.na(df[,7]),7]<-mean(df[,7], na.rm=T)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's one more way to skin this cat with `replace`:

```
d <- data.frame(a=1:5, b=c(1,2,NA,4,NA)) # example data
transform(d, b=replace(b, is.na(b), mean(b, na.rm=TRUE)))
```